# Grails: Why is <g:link> not emitting links?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have:

```
<td>
   <g:link controller="dashboard" action="view">Dashboard</g:link>
   <a href="fkd.co">Hello</a>
</td>
```

The result is:

> Dashboard [Hello](http://fkd.co)

Comment: If you have controller and view, g:link should be correct. It is also correct even without controller. Could you provide more info? Maybe you have codec in config?

Comment: See the source code generated. Seek for errors in your console view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that `<g:link>` was [overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638869/is-possible-to-overwrite-the-behaviour-of-the-methods-createlink-and-creat) and it was made only to create the links if the logged in user has access to that link otherwise emit the body text. The code looks like:

```
def link = { attrs, body ->

        def url = "/${pageScope.controllerName}/${attrs.action}"

        if( !securityService.isLoggedIn() ||
            securityService?.hasAccessToUri("/${pageScope.controllerName}/${attrs.action}") ) {

            def originalTagBean = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')

            originalTagBean.link.call(attrs, body)
        } else {
            out << body()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like your gsp page has not been compiled at all. Check source in the web browser. You should run embedded server with run-app command and then access the page.